# How do I save and retrieve more than one var in local storage.

Tags: javascript

I have created a app that lets you add classes to local storage. The problem I am having is after I have added more than one entry, when I reload the page only one entry is showing up from local storage.

```
"use strict";
var $ = function(id) { return document.getElementById(id); };


    var className = [];
    var classNumber = [];
    var startDate = [];
    var classLength = [];
    var classWeekday = [];
    var classTime = [];
    var classDescription = [];

var displayClassList = function() {

    var className = localStorage.className;
    var classNumber = localStorage.classNumber;
    var startDate = localStorage.startDate;
    var classLength = localStorage.classLength;
    var classWeekday = localStorage.classWeekday;
    var classTime = localStorage.classTime;
    var classDescription = localStorage.classDescription;

    $("classesHeader").innerHTML = ("Classes");
    $("name").innerHTML = ("Names");
    $("number").innerHTML = ("Number");
    $("start").innerHTML = ("Start");
    $("length").innerHTML = ("Length");
    $("weekday").innerHTML = ("Weekday");
    $("time").innerHTML = ("Time");
    $("description").innerHTML = ("Description");

        var table = $("classesTable")
        var row = table.insertRow(table.rows.length);
        var cell = row.insertCell(0);
        var cell2 = row.insertCell(1);
        var cell3 = row.insertCell(2);
        var cell4 = row.insertCell(3);
        var cell5 = row.insertCell(4);
        var cell6 = row.insertCell(5);
        var cell7 = row.insertCell(6);
        cell.innerHTML = className;
        cell2.innerHTML = classNumber;
        cell3.innerHTML = startDate;
        cell4.innerHTML = classLength;
        cell5.innerHTML = classWeekday;
        cell6.innerHTML = classTime;
        cell7.innerHTML = classDescription;


};
    var addToTable = function() { 

    var className = $("className").value;
    var classNumber = $("classNumber").value;
    var startDate = $("startDate").value;
    var classLength = $("classLength").value;
    var classWeekday = $("classWeekday").value;
    var classTime = $("classTime").value;
    var classDescription = $("classDescription").value;

    localStorage.className = className;
    localStorage.classNumber = classNumber;
    localStorage.startDate = startDate;
    localStorage.classLength = classLength;
    localStorage.classWeekday = classWeekday;
    localStorage.classTime = classTime;
    localStorage.classDescription = classDescription;

    displayClassList();


};
var clearForm = function() {
    $("className").value = "";  
    $("classNameError").firstChild.nodeValue = "*";
    $("classNumber").value = "";    
    $("classNumberError").firstChild.nodeValue = "*";
    $("startDate").value = "";  
    $("startDateError").firstChild.nodeValue = "*";
    $("classLength").value = "";    
    $("classLengthError").firstChild.nodeValue = "*";
    $("classWeekday").value = "";   
    $("weekdayError").firstChild.nodeValue = "*";
    $("classTime").value = "";  
    $("timeError").firstChild.nodeValue = "*";
    $("classDescription").value = "";   
    $("classDescriptionError").firstChild.nodeValue = "*";
    //tasks.length = 0;
    //localStorage.tasks = "";
   // $("classList").value = "";
    $("className").focus();
};



window.onload = function() {
    displayClassList();
    $("register").onclick = addToTable;
    $("reset_form").onclick = clearForm;   

};


<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<title>Class Catalog Maintenance</title>
<style>
    body {
        font-family: Verdana, Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
        font-size: 100%;
        background-color: white;
        width: 700px;
        margin: 0 auto;
        border: 3px solid blue;
        padding: 0 2em 1em;
    }
    h1 { 
        font-size: 150%;
        color: blue;
        margin-bottom: .5em;
    }
    label {
        float: left;
        width: 9.5em;
    }
    input {
        width: 22em;
        margin-right: 1em;
        margin-bottom: 1em;
    }
    span {
        color: red;
    }

    input[type=button] {
        width: 10em;
    }
    p {
        margin: 0;
    }
    td {
        width: 7em;
    }
</style>
</head>

<body>
<main>
    <h1>Class Catalog Maintenance</h1>

    <h2>Add a class</h2>
        <label>Class Name:</label>
            <input type="text" name="className" id="className">
            <span id="classNameError">*</span><br>
        <label>Class Number:</label>
            <input type="text" name="classNumber" id="classNumber">
             <span id="classNumberError">*</span><br>
        <label>Start Date:</label>
         <input type="text" name="startDate" id="startDate">
            <span id="startDateError">*</span><br>
            <label>Class Length (in weeks):</label>
            <select name="classLength" id="classLength">
                <option value="">Select an option</option>
                <option>10</option>
                <option>7.5</option>
                <option>6</option>
            </select>
            <span id="classLengthError">*</span><br><br>
            <label>Weekday and Time:</label>
            <select name="classWeekday" id="classWeekday">
            <option value="">Select an option</option>
                <option>TTH</option>
                <option>MWF</option>
                <option>TWTH</option>
            </select>
               <span id="weekdayError">*</span>
             <select name="classTime" id="classTime">
            <option value="">Select an option</option>
                <option>8:00am</option>
                <option>9:00am</option>
                <option>10:00am</option>
                <option>11:00am</option>
                <option>12:00pm</option>
                <option>1:00pm</option>
                 <option>2:00pm</option>
                <option>3:00pm</option>
                <option>4:00pm</option>
                 <option>5:00pm</option>
                <option>6:00pm</option>
            </select>
            <span id="timeError">*</span><br><br>
        <label>Class Description:</label>
          <span id="classDescriptionError">*</span><br><br>
            <textarea name="classDescription" id="classDescription" rows="5" cols="40"></textarea>
            <br><br>

        <input type="button" id="register" value="Add">
        <input type="button" id="reset_form" value="Clear">

    <h2 id="classesHeader">&nbsp;</h2>
    <table id="classesTable">
        <tr>
            <th id="name" align="left"></th>
            <th id="number" align="left"></th>
            <th id="start" align="left"></th>
            <th id="length" align="left"></th>
            <th id="weekday" align="left"></th>
            <th id="time" align="left"></th>
            <th id="description" align="left"></th>
        </tr>
    </table>

</main>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

Your are using single localStorage variables so it logic behavior that only single row is saved.

Create helper method:

```
function getClasses(){

  var classes;
  if (typeof localStorage.classes === "undefined")
    classes=[];//new array 
    else
     classes=JSON.parse(localStorage.classes);//get classes String and parse it to JS array

  return classes;
}
```

Above function gets classes array from localStorage, in localStorage we can not save complex objects so we need to parse it to String and get from it by parse method which is parsing String to js objects.

Change code to:

```
var addToTable = function() { 

  var className = $("className").value;
  var classNumber = $("classNumber").value;
  var startDate = $("startDate").value;
  var classLength = $("classLength").value;
  var classWeekday = $("classWeekday").value;
  var classTime = $("classTime").value;
  var classDescription = $("classDescription").value;

  var classes=getClasses(); //use helper method

  var newClass={};
  newClass.className = className;
  newClass.classNumber = classNumber;
  newClass.startDate = startDate;
  newClass.classLength = classLength;
  newClass.classWeekday = classWeekday;
  newClass.classTime = classTime;
  newClass.classDescription = classDescription;


  classes.push(newClass); //add class to array

  localStorage.classes=JSON.stringify(classes);//save with changes as String

  displayClassList();


};
```

Next display All classes not only single:

```
var displayClassList = function() {

  var classes=getClasses();

  $("classesHeader").innerHTML = ("Classes");
  $("name").innerHTML = ("Names");
  $("number").innerHTML = ("Number");
  $("start").innerHTML = ("Start");
  $("length").innerHTML = ("Length");
  $("weekday").innerHTML = ("Weekday");
  $("time").innerHTML = ("Time");
  $("description").innerHTML = ("Description");

    var table = $("classesTable")

    for (var i=0; i<classes.length; i++){ //loop for all classes from local storage

    var row = table.insertRow(table.rows.length);
    var cell = row.insertCell(0);
    var cell2 = row.insertCell(1);
    var cell3 = row.insertCell(2);
    var cell4 = row.insertCell(3);
    var cell5 = row.insertCell(4);
    var cell6 = row.insertCell(5);
    var cell7 = row.insertCell(6);
    cell.innerHTML = className;
    cell2.innerHTML = classNumber;
    cell3.innerHTML = startDate;
    cell4.innerHTML = classLength;
    cell5.innerHTML = classWeekday;
    cell6.innerHTML = classTime;
    cell7.innerHTML = classDescription;

    }

};
```